# Python, iterated list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The class Item has a member function text() that returns a list of strings.
The class Dictionary has a member function items() that returns a list of Items.
dict is an instance of Dictionary.
I want to test if all characters in all strings in all items in dict are ASCII.
I tried

```
all(ord(ch) < 128 for ch in s for s in item.text() for item in dict.items())
```

This gives the error message "global name 's' not defined".
What is the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the `for` clauses needs to be the other way around. The innermost loop comes last, the outmost loop comes first.

```
all(ord(ch) < 128 for item in dict.items() for s in item.text() for ch in s)
```